# Phoenix Resolve Request Host from %Plug.Conn{} remote ip

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, hostname

A little summary of what I'm trying to do. I have a Phoenix app running on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance and I'm sending REST API requests containing PDFs for manipulation (splitting, merging etc). Each Request is saved in the database. This is what my `requests` schema looks like:

```
 schema "requests" do
    field :body, :string
    field :endpoint, :string
    field :method, :string
    field :request_host, :string
    field :response_body, :string
    field :response_code, :integer
    field :work_group_id, :integer
    field :identifier, :string
    field :responded_at, :utc_datetime

    timestamps()
  end
```

Through Graphql, I'm making a request from a separate RAILS server and displaying the hostname, `inserted_at` field, and `response_code` field of all the requests.

I'm experiencing problems trying to resolve the client's host name. This is the Erlang method I'm using where the method argument remote_ip is relatively `conn.remote_ip`:

```
 {:ok, {:hostent, request_host, _, _, _, _}} = :inet.gethostbyaddr(remote_ip)
```

This method returns my Phoenix app's request host and not the clients'.  
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In the described process there is no notion of any _“client”_ at all.

Comment: Currently I'm sending the requests through a REST CLIENT(insomnia) onto the server.

Comment: It did not make things any clearer. Who’s IP do you expect to catch?

Comment: remote_ip - the IP of the client, example: {151, 236, 219, 228}. This field is meant to be overwritten by plugs that understand e.g. the X-Forwarded-For header or HAProxy’s PROXY protocol. It defaults to peer’s IP. (This is a explanation of the conn.remote_ip I'm trying to use)

Comment: Is the Elastic Beanstalk configured with a reverse proxy nginx? It might set the ip address on the conn. There are several plug packages that set the conn.remote_ip from the X-forwarded-for header.

Answer (score 2):

This library is available to simplify handling of IP addresses behind proxies.

https://github.com/ajvondrak/remote_ip

The author has a nice writeup of applicable use-cases and why the library is probably a better choice than rolling your own: [here](https://github.com/ajvondrak/remote_ip#background)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html):

> [The `remote_ip`] field is meant to be overwritten by plugs that understand e.g. the `X-Forwarded-For` header or HAProxy's PROXY protocol. It defaults to peer's IP.

This is elaborated upon [here](https://www.cogini.com/blog/getting-the-client-public-ip-address-in-phoenix/):

> When your app is running behind a proxy like Nginx, then the request will look like it's coming from Nginx, i.e. the IP will be 127.0.0.1. Similarly, If Nginx is behind a CDN, then all the requests will come from the IP of the CDN.

So you can write a plug to overwrite the `remote_ip` field of the `Plug.Conn`. Following is an example of such a plug. This example is copied from [this blog post](https://www.cogini.com/blog/getting-the-client-public-ip-address-in-phoenix/).

```
defmodule MyApp.Plug.PublicIp do
  @moduledoc "Get public IP address of request from x-forwarded-for header"
  @behaviour Plug
  @app :my_app

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(%{assigns: %{ip: _}} = conn, _opts), do: conn
  def call(conn, _opts) do
    process(conn, Plug.Conn.get_req_header(conn, "x-forwarded-for"))
  end

  def process(conn, []) do
    Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :ip, to_string(:inet.ntoa(get_peer_ip(conn))))
  end
  def process(conn, vals) do
    if Application.get_env(@app, :trust_x_forwarded_for, false) do ip_address = get_ip_address(conn, vals) # Rewrite standard remote_ip field with value from header
      # See https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html
      conn = %{conn | remote_ip: ip_address}

      Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :ip, to_string(:inet.ntoa(ip_address)))
    else
      Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :ip, to_string(:inet.ntoa(get_peer_ip(conn))))
    end
  end

  defp get_ip_address(conn, vals)
  defp get_ip_address(conn, []), do: get_peer_ip(conn)
  defp get_ip_address(conn, [val | _]) do
    # Split into multiple values
    comps = val
      |> String.split(~r{\s*,\s*}, trim: true)
      |> Enum.filter(&(&1 != "unknown"))          # Get rid of "unknown" values
      |> Enum.map(&(hd(String.split(&1, ":"))))   # Split IP from port, if any
      |> Enum.filter(&(&1 != ""))                 # Filter out blanks
      |> Enum.map(&(parse_address(&1)))           # Parse address into :inet.ip_address tuple
      |> Enum.filter(&(is_public_ip(&1)))         # Elminate internal IP addreses, e.g. 192.168.1.1

    case comps do
      [] -> get_peer_ip(conn)
      [comp | _] -> comp
    end
  end

  @spec get_peer_ip(Plug.Conn.t) :: :inet.ip_address
  defp get_peer_ip(conn) do
    {ip, _port} = conn.peer
    ip
  end

  @spec parse_address(String.t) :: :inet.ip_address
  defp parse_address(ip) do
    case :inet.parse_ipv4strict_address(to_charlist(ip)) do
      {:ok, ip_address} -> ip_address
      {:error, :einval} -> :einval
    end
  end

  # Whether the input is a valid, public IP address
  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network
  @spec is_public_ip(:inet.ip_address | atom) :: boolean
  defp is_public_ip(ip_address) do
    case ip_address do
      {10, _, _, _}     -> false
      {192, 168, _, _}  -> false
      {172, second, _, _} when second >= 16 and second <= 31 -> false
      {127, 0, 0, _}    -> false
      {_, _, _, _}      -> true
      :einval           -> false
    end
  end
end
```